# Loop code on request after it's finished?

Tags: python

I'm making a lottery ticket generator program for my grandparents. (They're Spanish, so most of the code is in Spanish too.)

How can I make it so:

1. It generates a custom number of tickets?
2. After it's finished, how can I loop the code on request? (e.g: 'do you want to do it again?' 'yes' *code starts again*)

Thanks in advance!

```
import random
options = ("Bonoloto", "Primitiva", "Euromillón", "Gordo")

reintegro = random.sample(range(1,9), 1) 
loteria = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
boleto = sorted(loteria)

while True:
    choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
    if choice in options:
        print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
        break
    else:
        print('Esa lotería no existe!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your main code into a function and loop through that function, so that program can respond based on the user's response on if they want to continue or not.

It's quite easy, here is the code to do that most of it is your code only, I just edited it a little:

```
import random
options = ("Bonoloto", "Primitiva", "Euromillón", "Gordo")

reintegro = random.sample(range(1,9), 1) 
loteria = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
boleto = sorted(loteria)

def lottery():
    choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
    if choice in options:
        print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
    else:
        print('Esa lotería no existe!')
    j= input('would you like to continue? ')
    return j
        
while True:
    i=lottery()
    
    if i=='yes' or i=='y':
        lottery()
    elif i=='no' or i=='n':
        break
    else:
        print('input not valid.')
        break
```

Translate the English part if required.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works correctly.

```
import random

options = ("Bonoloto", "Primitiva", "Euromillón", "Gordo")


def generate_ticket():
   
    more_tickets = True
    while True and more_tickets:
        choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
        if choice.title() in options:
            reintegro = random.sample(range(1, 9), 1)
            loteria = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
            boleto = sorted(loteria)
            print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
            response = input("Do you want to generate more ticket? (YES/NO): ")
            if response.upper() == "YES":
                more_tickets = True
            else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                more_tickets = False
        else:
            print('Esa lotería no existe!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_ticket()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my Spanish is okay-ish. To draw the numbers, just ask for them and move the generation to inside the loop. To make it replayable, I'd nest the while loop inside another one:

```py
import random
options = ("Bonoloto", "Primitiva", "Euromillón", "Gordo")

reintegro = random.sample(range(1,9), 1)[0]
seguir = True

while seguir:
    while True:
        choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
        if choice in options:
            break
        else:
            print('Esa lotería no existe!')

    boleta = []
    while True:
        try:
            n_boleta = int(input("Cuántas boleto quieres? "))
        except ValueError:
            # failed to cast `n_boleta` to a number
            print('Solo entiendo numeros')
        else:
            for _ in range(n_boleta):
                boleta.append(sorted(random.sample(range(1,50), 6)))
            break
    print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleta, 'con reintegro', reintegro)

    while True:
        # Make it case insensitive
        seguir_input = input('Quieres jugar de nuevo? [si/no] ' ).lower()
        if seguir_input not in ('si', 'no'):
            print('Solo entiendo si o no')
        else:
            break
    seguir = seguir_input == 'si'
```

Comment: Actually, I meant multiple sets of numbers, not numbers alone.

Comment: I changed the code to generate multiple draws of 6 numbers each

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of when to use the programming best practice of breaking your code into small functions. You can use the following  as one way to get what you need:

```
options = ("BONOLOTO", "PRIMITIVA", "EUROMILLÓN", "GORDO")

def crearBoletos(cantidad):
    boletos = []
    if not cantidad.isdigit():
        return boletos
    for i in range(int(cantidad)):
        reintegro = random.sample(range(1,9), 1)[0]
        loteria = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
        boletos += [(sorted(loteria), reintegro)]
    return boletos

while True:
    choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
    if choice.upper() in options:
        cantidad = input('Cuantos boletos quieres? ')
        print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:')
        for boleto, reintegro in crearBoletos(cantidad):
            print("*", boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
        repetir = input('Quieres hacerlo otra vez? [sí, no] ')
        if repetir.upper() in ["SI", "S", "SÍ"]:
            continue
        break
    else:
        print('Esa lotería no existe!')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when executed, it doesn't show anything.